# Nuance entre phylogénique et phylogénétique

Tags: terminologie, biologie

Dans un cours de biologie, les mots *phylogénétique* et *phylogénique* se succèdent sans que je ne parviennent vraiment à en saisir la nuance.

Toutefois, d’après les définitions du wiktionnaire de phylogénétique et phylogénique, j’ai l’intuition que ce qui est phylogénique a rapport de façon générale avec la classification de toutes les espèces alors que ce qui est phylogénétique s’intéresse au cas focal de la classification d’une espèce en particulier.

Ai-je raison ?

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas en toucher un mot à ton professeur ? Tu verras si lui y apporte une nuance.

Comment: Je suis candidat libre :P Et pis d’abord, je ne vous permet pas de me tutoyer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tous les dictionnaires que je viens de consulter donnent les adjectifs  *phylogénétique* et *phylogénique* comme interchangeables.
 Je pense que la meilleure précision soit donnée par le *Dictionnaire culturel en Langue Française* qui indique que « phylogénétique » est le terme actuel qui remplace « phylogénique » depuis depuis 1897.

> [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique) : Phylogénétique, phylogénique, adj.Relatif à la phylogénèse.

> [Dictionnaire de terminologie médiacle](http://www.bio-top.net/Terminologie/O/onto.htm) [Ontogénétique, Ontogénique] Ces adjectifs s'opposent à phylogénétique ou phylogénique, qui caractérisent ce qui se rapporte au développement de l'espèce.

> *Petit Robert* : **Phylogénique ou Phylogénétique**. Branche de la génétique traitant des modifications d'ordre génétique au sein d'une espèce animale ou végétale.

Le *Grand Larousse encyclopédique* ne donne qu'un seul terme  *Phylogénétique*.

Wikipedia a un article [*phylogénétique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique?oldformat=true) mais pas d'article *phylogénique*.

Comment: Wikipédia a un article sur tout :D Seulement, *phylogénique* redirige vers *[phylogénie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogénie)*.

Comment: @Fauve, oui, c'est ce que je disais, car phylogénie est le mot le plus proche.

Answer (score 3):

[Selon Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique/60593?q=phylog%C3%A9nique#60217), ces deux adjectifs ont la même signification :

Comment: Même chose pour le CNRTL : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique

Answer (score 0):

On parle de [*phylogénie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylog%C3%A9nie) mais de [*l'arbre phylogénétique*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbre_phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique) ou de la [classification phylogénétique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique). C'est à dire, le nom est *phylogénie*, mais l'adjectif est *phylogénétique*.

Neanmoins, je ne dirais pas que l'adjectif *phylogénique* est une erreur. D'abord, il pourrait s'agisser de l'usage plus ancien, avant de monter en puissance des methodes *génétiques* modernes (ce qui est la developpement des dernières decennies, alors que l'étude des liens de parenté est beaucoup plus ancienne - datante au moin de l'époque de Darwin.)

En outre, en principe, on pourrait parler des liens de parenté sans parler de génétique (compris comme la comparaison de séquences génétique):

- soit on les discute sur le niveau plus elevé (au niveau des génes entiers, des crhomosomes entiers)
- soit on parle de liens de parenté n'est pas présenté en séquence génétique - c'est à dire de liens [épigénétique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89pig%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique) ou de espèces bacteriennes herités... ou même de la langue maternelle.
- soit on peut parler de liens génétiques, mais pas liés au parenté, comme [le transfert horizontal de gènes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11808/nuance-entre-phylog%C3%A9nique-et-phylog%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique?rq=1)

Mais il s'agit ici des points assez techniques, qui sont peu probable de survenir dans un cours de biologie de la nature assez générale. Donc je dirais que *phylogénique=phylogénétique*.